# Why does System.Convert("0") throw a FormatException on some systems?

Tags: c#, crash, formatexception

The code is compiled in VS2008 targeting .NET3.5.  This is not reproducible on my system.  I suspect some sort of localization setting is at play but I don't know much about that.

All other valid numbers seem to work fine.  The bug is illustrated with this code (which causes the same exception but is not the production code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "";
            do
            {
                str = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\t\"{0}\"", Convert.ToDouble(str));
            }
            while (str != null);
        }
    }
}
```

At the command line, input of "0" crashes the app on at least one system I have encountered.

Stack trace from user's PC:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
```

Comment: What does crash mean? You don't get any error message or stack trace of any type?

Comment: You're blindly converting the console input to a double.  Have you tried validating its a number using `Double.TryParse()` first?

Comment: Crash means an exception that is not handled appropriately. I get a stack trace, but remember, this is a user's PC and I can't reproduce the issue on my machine.

Comment: @pomeroy, what stack trace? what exception? on what input? on what locale?

Comment: Maybe somebody just pulled a prank on your user and remapped his `0` key to the character `O`.

Comment: @George I have ascertained that the string being converted is "0". That is valid input (in my culture) but causes a FormatException on this user's PC.

Comment: @Samuel I appended the (relevant part of the) stack trace to the question. The exception (as stated in the question) is a FormatException. The input (as stated in the question) is "0". I do not understand the question "on what locale".

Comment: @Frédéric It even occurs when the UI has a default "0" and the app uses that value in the calculation. In other words, the user didn't input any value, "0" or "o".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember this problem from a question a while back.  The Parse() methods are affected by the user overrides in the Control Panel + Region and Language applet.  IIRC, it is especially sensitive to the "Negative sign symbol" setting.  Ask your user to correct the settings there.

The reference question [is here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4f52ff21-2afe-41c8-aa4e-61acd32dc4a2/).

Answer (score 5):

If your problem is related to current culture, try converting to Double using Invariant Culture:

```
Convert.ToDouble("0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to prove that it's not because of the code(or the CultureInfo), I can prove that for all cultures in .NET, a string "0" can be converted to double correctly.

```
string inputNumber = "0";
foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
   try
   {
       double d = Convert.ToDouble(inputNumber, culture);
   }
   catch
   {
      Console.WriteLine(culture.Name);
   }
}
Console.WriteLine("end");
Console.Read();
```

It outputs nothing but an "end".

Comment: Interesting. And yet, the crash is undoubtedly caused by the input of "0" to the Convert.ToDouble method.  Any ideas?

Comment: @pomeroy: I think you can change `str = Console.ReadLine();` to `str = "0";` and try again to see if the app still crashes.

Comment: Confirmed: `Convert.ToDouble("0")` causes FormatException.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to culture settings. As I know in some culture settings you should type in 0.0 to be able to convert to double

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does crash when you input `0`.

It will, of course, crash when you input anything that is not a number. This means that it will crash if you input an empty string (in other words, just push enter). I imagine this is what you are experiencing.

You code would work (for only numbers) if you change it to this:

```
string str = "";
do
{
    str = Console.ReadLine();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        Console.WriteLine("\t\"{0}\"", Convert.ToDouble(str));
}
while (str != "");
```

Comment: How wonderfully condescending.  Apparently I don't have the reputation to down-vote you, but I wish I did.

Comment: I don't think he is being condescending. Your routine does not do any kind of validation whatsoever, and you are just saying that we should "trust" that an user has really typed a valid number, even if, considering the kind of exception that was thrown, that does not seem to make any sense at all. Sorry, but if something may go wrong, it will - and you code does not do anything to avoid that.

Comment: Neither of you are reading the question.  The routine is not code in production that is causing this crash, the routine has been shown to isolate the problem on the user's PC.

Comment: @pomeroy: I wasn't trying to be condescending. Sorry for upsetting you. Your code will crash when you input anything that is not a number. The exit condition for your loop requires you to input something that is not a number, so it will crash whenever you try to exit.

Comment: He wasn't being condescending.

Comment: The question is, "Why does System.Convert("0") [crash] on some systems?"  And his answer is, "I don't think it does crash..."  That's condescending. Now, Matt's probably a good guy and I don't hold it against him, but it was condescending.

Answer (score 0):

The CurrentCulture CultureInfo instance is probably to blame. [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx) call, after all, simply returns the result of [Double.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx). This, as documented, uses the current culture's NumberFormatInfo to figure things out.

Comment: Yeah, that's my thinking too.  Unfortunately this is not an answer, per se.